# Publish WFS from PostGIS SQL view

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wfs, sql-view

I am trying to create a public WFS service with GeoServer from a PostGIS SQL view, but this does not load in QGIS. If I publish from a PostGIS table the WFS service is loaded normally.

Is it possible to publish a WFS service from an SQL view?

Comment: It should treat the VIEW like a regular TABLE. Have you tested the view directly in QGIS, without going through WFS?

Comment: Now trying directly with Postgis connection, but i get message "Failed to get layers", i working in Ubuntu 18.04 operating system

Comment: Does the service work outside of QGIS using the view?   Which version of PostgreSQL/PostGIS are you using. Which version of GeoServer

Comment: Yes out of qgis if load see https://geo.gporellana.gob.ec/apps/visor/                      postgres version is 9.5.1 postgis version is 2.2.2 and geoserver version is 2.14.1

Comment: Does your view have a column that could serve as a primary key, preferably in the first position ?

Comment: yes if the view has the gid column in the first position which is the primary key in the source table

Comment: the log of QGIS says: Unable to get list of spatially enabled tables from the database.
ERROR: permiso denegado al esquema topology

Comment: If the WFS call like `https://geo.gporellana.gob.ec/geoinfo/gadpo/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=gadpo%3At_alcantarilla&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&format_options=callback%3AgetJson&srsName=EPSG%3A4326` from the portal is using a PostGIS view, then isn't the answer to your question **Yes** you can use a view.

Comment: If that is what I do not understand, I will change the version of qgis from 3.10 to 3.4 to try

Comment: You may need to cast the geometry column by adding something like ::geometry(point, 4326), supposing in this example that your geometries are points, and your CRS 4326).

Comment: The question is about WFS, WFS works in the web portal,  QGIS should be accessing the WFS directly not the database. The question seems misworded, discussing how QQIS attaches to the database is not relevant to the asked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said in comments

> the log of QGIS says: Unable to get list of spatially enabled tables
>   from the database. ERROR: permiso denegado al esquema topology

And you also said that the WFS service is accessible from your webmap.

This means that a different database user is requesting the data in Geoserver than in Qgis. Moreover, the DB user in QGIS is lacking priviledges on the schema holding the view (and/or on the schema containing the data referred in the view)

--> you need to grant the usage priv:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA topology TO myQGISuser;
```

Comment: i execute GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA topology TO myQGISuser, but now i obtain message in Qgis "Error:permission denied to the layer relationship"

Comment: @JavierAguilar if you want to display the view in QGIS, you need to grant everything that is required (access to the DB, usage on the schema, read on the involved tables etc). Nmtoken comment is however very relevant: if you want to show the WFS, then accessing the view directly should be out of considerations

Comment: restart QGIS and it works by running GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA topology TO myQGISuser;, I did this for administration work what. I have pending is to know why the views are not loaded with the wfs service so that users can use it, I have noticed that it does not work when it is a view, for wfs created from tables if the load works, I think that it is because of the id field that is in the view but Qgis does not seem to recognize it